# WSO2 Application Server will redirect to "/carbon" upon 404 error is expected

Tags: http-status-code-404, wso2, wso2-wsas

I am being confused by wso2 aplication server. When i access a non-exist page, it will always redirect to carbon console, I have studied the xml config files, but find no luck.
I just want to know how to make it just report 404 error when it does happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer, the reason is the carbon app occupied the context root, so all request to non exist context-roots will be received by carbon app. 
After changing the carbon WebContextRoot in carbon.xml, all seems ok now.