# WSO2 Carbon 404 Error Redirection for Webapp Deployment?

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-404, wso2, wso2-as

We are using WSO2 Carbon 4.2.0 through the WSO2 Application Server (AS) package.  In replacing an older, highly customized Carbon installation (provided by a company that no longer supports the product, has abandoned it and refuses to work on it, and left us no details on how/what they modified in Carbon), we have deployed a couple web applications in the webapps container as they were deployed before in the older instance.  We have changed our WebContextRoot in the carbon.xml from the default "/" to a sub-URL of ex: "/stuff", as is also detailed in the self-answered SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23933482/wso2-application-server-will-redirect-to-carbon-upon-404-error-is-expected).  However the answer given there is not detailed in what the OP actually encountered when he modified his WSO2 instance.

In testing the above configuration we noticed that if a user were to go to a non-existent web address on the server, depending on the format of the URL they are either:

1. redirected to a blank page;
2. receive a "500 Internal server error" (I suspect this is the embedded Tomcat?);
3. get sent to the Carbon login page (which we definitely do *not* want to happen for security reasons); or
4. get an XML document stating:

   ```
   <faultString> The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) /stuff/services/nonexistantservicename </faultString>
   ```

At least in the case of missing content we wish the user to be sent to a standardized 404 error page, or at the least be sent an HTTP 404 error by the server.  For services the XML error is palatable, we can deal with that.

The only option for us right now to circumvent this issue is to place a proxy in front of the WSO2 instance, which would be another layer to manage and tune, and possibly degrade performance.  Please know that I am not a programmer but just an admin with DevOps experience.  I would not know how to handle this with e.g. a Java solution or re-coding parts of WSO2.  Customizing the core product would also hamper future upgrades of WSO2, a scenario we are trying to dig ourselves out of now as detailed above.  Is there no internal WSO2 mechanism to handle non-existent content?  Can we not redirect any errors to a standard canned response page?

Comment: Your question is not so clear. What is your actual requirement?

Comment: I thought my final question is quite clear: Can we direct standard HTTP errors like 404 to custom pages rather than the current situation?  HTTP 404 is a standardized error code for non-existent content on a web server: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html .